# How to bake normal map?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Why is the blender-baked normal map lighter than the map from `Marmoset`?

left- `Blender`

right- `Marmoset`

[image]

Comment: I think that the difference comes from the fact that the image on the left is 32-Bit Float, the one on the right is not but I don't know more

Comment: Please check if the flat pixels have a value of (0.5, 0.5, 1.0).. If so, then the map is correct, but is being transformed to sRGB when drawing it to the screen.

Comment: looks like the left image is in the `Linear` color space and the right image in the `sRGB` color space.